# .htaccess forcing HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I am trying to force HTTPS on a domain. It must be done using a method that works by domain name and not port number (due to host structure/setup).

My closest attempt was:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works when typing "mydomain.com" into the address bar, automatically redirecting to "https://mydomain.com" but when I type "www.mydomain.com" it does not work. I assume it is a syntax issue as I am very new to htaccess and have spent about 4 hours trying to create a solution from other's code.

Any chance of a pointer?

---

To make the setup a little more understandable.

`/public_html/` - All files in this folder relate to `www.mydomain.com`
`/public_html/subfolder` - These folders contain files also relating to `mydomain.com`
`/public_html/subdomain` - These folders contain files relating to `www.myotherdomain.com`

My other domains are subdomains of `mydomain.com` for to be listed in the cpanel on the host. 
For example: `subdomain.mydomain.com` is the same as `www.myotherdomain.com`.

Hopefully that clears up the structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your redirect happens whenever a request is made to the exact domain `mydomain.com` (that's what the RewriteCond is testing for). It doesn't apply to any other domains and doesn't detect HTTPS. Use this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I am using Bluehost as my host. Their set up method is that the primary site (the one I am trying to use https with) is listed under "public_html".

All my other sites are in subfolders of "public_html" and are affected by the .htaccess file, causing all domains to now redirect to "mydomain.com"

Comment: @Daniel I see. I will update my answer. Are any of your other sites subdomains of mydomain, or all they all different domains?

Comment: I have a domain name for each, but for them to be on the cpanel, they must be assigned subdomains. For example: **www.mydomain.com** and **subdomains.mydomain.com** (which is also **www.myotherdomains.com**)

Comment: @Daniel And you only want to force HTTPS on `www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com`, right?

Comment: correct. I have updated original post with layout, to clear it up a little. Cheers.

Comment: Hi @Daniel. With the update I just made it should redirect `http://mydomain.com` and `http://www.mydomain.com` both to `https://www.mydomain.com`. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thank you for your time, a great help!